# Windows 10 won't boot after Ubuntu installation

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows, 17.10

I was fed up with Windows so decided I'd try out Linux as a complete beginner. Unfortunately I've ended up messing up my Windows 10 boot. Like a complete fool, I tinkered about with partitions to try to create space for Ubuntu and think I obliterated my recovery drive, though can still see files in my Windows partition. I've made backups of the important files but nevertheless would prefer recovering the installation over re-writing over everything and having to reinstall everything.

I've tried to follow steps suggested on other sites to attempt to recover the Windows boot, but to no avail. I installed Boot Repair today and it produced this ubuntu pastebin output:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YfXHG7ktmY/

I tried running the Boot Repair auto-repair function but it told me "GPT Detected..." and asked me to create a drive >1mb large with grub flag and no formatting. I tried that, after installing GParted, but it didn't seem to alter the outcome of the message; GPT Detected..." with the same prompt for a >1mb large partition happens again.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Is this a grub or uefi based computer?

Comment: Hardware is UEFI. But cannot tell if you had Windows in BIOS or UEFI boot mode as sda1 & sda2 are missing. Windows only boots from gpt with UEFI and only from MBR(msdos) with BIOS. And you have to know if Windows was UEFI or BIOS to know how to recover it. It could have been BIOS on MBR drive with sda1 as Windows recovery & sda2 as Windows boot partition with its boot files. And you somehow converted drive from MBR to gpt. Or it could be you just erased first two partitions with Windows boot files. Was Windows BIOS or UEFI?If Windows 10 from Vendor UEFI, if upgrade from Windows 7 the BIOS.

Comment: Thanks bud for the quick response. It's only a year old HP Pavilion Notebook model 15-au109na. It came with Windows 10 pre-installed.